# Substitution Method : Why this recurrence changes inequality & equality sign And Why inductive step used smaller values as a next value

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, recurrence, induction

I was reading CLRS book to understand solving recurrences using Substitution method and found following example:

```
   Recurrence, T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n
   Guess Solution, T(n) = O(nlgn)
   Proof that T(n) ≤ cnlgn
```

[image]

My questions are:

Q1: why the solving equation changes their signs between  inequality & equality sign `≤ , =` ?

Q2: We know that in mathematical induction, inductive step is the next value,So if current value is **n** then next value should be **(n+1)**.But Why they used **n/2** as the next inductive step ?

Please help me to explain these question.It will rally help me to understand Substitution Method.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 : The two equalities are just rewritings of the previous line since log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b) and log(2) = 1

Q2 : For the induction step, since we write T(n) in function of T(n/2), one step is directly a 2-factor. If the recurrence formula was T(n) = f(T(n-1)), you would have the classical induction step with a 1-addition.

Note also that you assume in this proof that T(1) can be done in constant time.

Comment: Thanks @Damien Prot for ur reply, After reading your helpful reply i've 2 more questions regarding my post questions for more better understanding:                                         **Q1.  (cn lg(n/2) + n),  (cn lg n - cn lg 2 + n)  and  (cn lg n - cn + n ) are equivalent, that's why used Equal sign.However the Inequality is still there between R.H.S and L.H.S. 
inequality ?**
                             
          **Q2.  The next value inductive step depend on how the Recurrence Relation is Evolving.Based on this, it could be Greater or Less than the previous input size ?**   Thanks

Comment: Q1 : yes, that's it. Q2 : yes, the inductive step depends on the recurrence relation.

Comment: Thanks @Damien Prot .Also you said, T(1) can be done in constant time. I apply T(n) = cnlgn for T(1) = c.1. lg 1 = 0 then why it is constant time ?

Comment: Imagine that T(1) can be done in O(n²), clearly your complexity for T(n) cannot O(n lg n).

Comment: Thanks @Damien Prot. got it